# Where did the number of 32 Eth to become a validator come from?

Tags: proof-of-stake, validators

What was the Math behind coming to the number of 32 Eth as a threshold to become a validator? Which parameters were considered to come to this number? Did the parameters of Eth distribution in the community, and total members in the community play a role? What role does the Sybil attack or 51% attack play in determining the number 32 ETH?

Comment: Probably the following doesn't answer all your questions, but you might find it useful: https://twitter.com/toghrulmaharram/status/1530708903440302082

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is:

> The 32 ETH stake size is a trade-off between network overhead, number of validators, and time to finality.

As for the long answer, I will try to sum up the explanations from [Ben Edgington](https://eth2book.info/altair/part2/incentives/staking#stake-size) and [Vitalik](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/serenity_design_rationale#Why-32-ETH-validator-sizes) that I encourage you to read for a more thorough understanding.

The math behind 32 ETH is the following:

> if *n* is the number of validators in a network, *f* is the time to finalize a block, and *ω* is the overhead in messages per second, then we have:
> *ω ≥ 2n/f*.

To put this in concrete terms, the hard limit on the number of validators is the total Ether supply divided by the stake size. If we take a stake of 32 ETH and assume a total supply of 2^27 ETH this means *n*=2^22. With that, we want to reach finality in two epochs (=768 seconds), which leads to about 11,000 messages per second which is possible thanks to BLS aggregate signature.

---

I've summed up the "official" explanation. In my opinion, there is also the fact that when the choice was made, 32 ETH didn't seem as high as it is now. So a rule of thumb was made to ensure decentralization and communication going well.

If you are interested, linked to this subject is a proposition of Vitalik to [usher](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/single_slot_finality) the protocol to single slot finality, thus changing drastically the activity of validators.